# How to properly swap between vertical pills and tabs based on screen resolution with angular-ui-bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I have a default (horizontal) tabset made with **angular-ui-bootstrap**.

```
<uib-tabset active="0">
    <uib-tab index="0" heading="Foobar">
        <div ng-include="foobar.html"></div>
    </uib-tab>
    <!-- Other tabs... -->
</uib-tabset>
```

I'd like to transform it to a vertical "pills" tabset for mobile.

```
<uib-tabset active="0" vertical="true" type="pills">
    <uib-tab index="0" heading="Foobar">
        <div ng-include="foobar.html"></div>
    </uib-tab>
    <!-- Other tabs... -->
</uib-tabset>
```

Since I'm working with Bootstrap 3 I tried the following workaround:

```
<div class="visible-xs-block">
    <uib-tabset active="0" vertical="true" type="pills">
        <uib-tab index="0" heading="foobar">
            <div ng-include="foobar.htm"></div>
        </uib-tab>
        <!-- Other tabs... -->
    </uib-tabset>
</div>

<div class="hidden-xs">
    <uib-tabset active="0">
        <uib-tab index="0" heading="foobar">
            <div ng-include="foobar.html"></div>
        </uib-tab>
        <!-- Other tabs... -->
    </uib-tabset>
</div>
```

It "works" but I think it's not really efficient. I also have so issues with directives since some elements are defined twice (ng-include are duplicates).

Do you now how I could properly handle it in a controller or something?

Comment: Maybe you can use `ng-attr-*` for this. Using a variable you set when `window` gets resized.

Comment: @Arg0n You're right! I saw in the doc that vertical is already binded with angular scope and "type" attribute could be bind with angular using ng-attr-*, I almost finish it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of duplicating your code, you can do something in the lines of this:

```
<uib-tabset active="0" vertical="myIsSmallScreenVariable" ng-attr-type="myIsSmallScreenVariable ? 'pills' : null">
  <uib-tab index="0" heading="foobar">
    <div ng-include="foobar.htm"></div>
  </uib-tab>
  <!-- Other tabs... -->
</uib-tabset>
```